# If you have me, you don't have

Tags: riddle

I hope you guys like this one:

```
If you have me, you don't have
If you give me, you will displease
You can't make me, feel at ease
For sure not trace me on a graph

You could as well not read the rhymes
but you'll find me between the lines

What am I?
```

It's pretty easy I think!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe it's nothing but could it be

> "nothing" ?

Comment: That's what I'd have answered.

Comment: That was easy, wasn't it? :D

Comment: I can only speak for my self - yes :) However, I like your style!